# How to add multiple dimension constraints to Capacitated Vehicle Routing Problem (CVRP)?

Tags: python, or-tools

I am new to `OR tools` and trying to add weight and volume (height, length, width separately) constraints in the capacitated vehicle routing problem. The main idea of not using the volume constraint directly is because, for example, consider a truck of dimensions 10x10x10 and an item of dimensions 12x1x1. However, practically the volume of the item is less than the volume of the truck, it is not possible to ship this product in the truck. Hence, I want to consider length, width, and height separately. The subtle issue while handling the width and length constraints is that the item can be placed vertically or horizontally. I want the algorithm to consider this as well. Any help would be appreciated.

**Working `CVRP` code with single capacity constraint:**

```
def demand_callback(from_index):
    """Returns the demand of the node."""
    # Convert from routing variable Index to demands NodeIndex.
    from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
    return data['demands'][from_node]

demand_callback_index = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback(
    demand_callback)
routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(
    demand_callback_index,
    0,  # null capacity slack
    data['vehicle_capacities'],  # vehicle maximum capacities
    True,  # start cumul to zero
    'Capacity')
```

To this above working solution, I want to add dimension constraint.

Reference: [OR-Tools: CVRP](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/cvrp)

Comment: don't get it, you can have any number of dimension you want i.e. simply duplicate and adapt this code...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Mizux, thanks for your reply. I have updated my question, Hope it is clear now.

Comment: or-tools can only handle either weight or volume.